# Lottie React Native not executing in Android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement lottie framework in React Native. Its working perfectly in iOS. When I'm trying to run the app in Android and getting the following error. I don't know what is the issue and where it is coming from. I have searched over the internet and I'm not able to find the solution.

```
/Users/xxxx/Desktop/BouncingBall/node_modules/lottie-react-native/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java
Error:(86, 46) error: cannot find symbol method toHashMap()
Error:Execution failed for task ':lottie-react-native:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

/app/build.gradle file

```
  apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile


project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bouncingball"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    provided "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    compile project(':lottie-react-native')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

settings.gradle file

```
rootProject.name = 'BouncingBall'
include ':lottie-react-native'
project(':lottie-react-native').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/lottie-react-native/lib/android')

include ':app'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The link command does not fully works. You need to link the library manually. If you don't know how to do this, please post your build.gradle and settings.gradle.

Edit after seeing the gradle files:

In here you have lottie twice:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':lottie-react-native')
    ...
    compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
}
```

The second one is the one recommended in the docs but that didn't work for me, I assume for a new RN version. The first one is the one added by the link command and that should work. Try commenting the second compile and see if that finished the build.

Comment: @sfratini.I have posted the build.gradle and settings.gradle file. Can you please check now?

Comment: That is the root build.gradle. there should be another one inside the android/app folder .  Settings gradle looks fine

Comment: You have lottie compiled twice. Leave only the one that says project before and comment the one that says 2.2.5 at the end. See if that helps

Comment: still i'm getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run the code without --deviceID. Just run **npx react-native run-android** . It works for me.

Happy coding.